# SQL Join and Sum using ACCESS Database

Tags: sql

I'm a novice programmer with very limited knowledge of SQL. I've been trying for hours and have read all the resources I can find but can't seem to work out how to join these two tables and get the total invoice value using an ACCESS database.

**TblInvoices**

`CustomerID`   `InvoiceAmount`

**TblCustomers**

`CustomerID`   `CustomerName`   `CustomerRep`

All I need is the CustomerName, their Rep and the total value of their invoices (OK Between certain dates but I've cracked that bit). I've tried Inner Joins and anything else I can find but without much luck.

As an idea...

```
"SELECT CustomerName, CustomerRep, Sum(InvoiceAmount) AS INVOICETOTAL
FROM TblCustomers, TblInvoices WHERE TblCustomers.CustomerID = TblInvoices.CustomerID
GROUP BY CustomerID"
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: This may get handy.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076336/how-to-get-sum-from-two-different-tables-that-are-linked-to-third-one .. I know its sql but still it will give you some idea about the concept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current query is close but since you have `CustomerName` and `CustomerRep` in the SELECT you need to `GROUP BY` those columns:

```
SELECT TblCustomers.CustomerName, 
  TblCustomers.CustomerRep, 
  Sum(TblInvoices.InvoiceAmount) AS INVOICETOTAL 
FROM TblCustomers
INNER JOIN TblInvoices 
  ON TblCustomers.CustomerID = TblInvoices.CustomerID 
GROUP BY TblCustomers.CustomerName, TblCustomers.CustomerRep;
```

MS Access requires that any columns appearing in the SELECT list be included in an aggregate function or in the `GROUP BY` clause when aggregation is being used. If you want to only `GROUP BY` the `CustomerId`, then you could also use a subquery to get the result:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, 
  c.CustomerRep, 
  i.INVOICETOTAL 
FROM TblCustomers c
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Sum(InvoiceAmount) AS INVOICETOTAL,
    CustomerID
  FROM TblInvoices 
  GROUP BY CustomerID
) i
  ON TblCustomers.CustomerID = i.CustomerID
```

Comment: Thank you so much - I truly appreciate your time. That now makes sense and has solved my issue. I think I can add the WHERE criteria in from here.