# mysql join across three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Similar question to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076336/how-to-get-sum-from-two-different-tables-that-are-linked-to-third-one) except that the three tables I have are hierarchical rather than two tables side by side.

The tables i have are

My top level clients table

```
id | name
1  | alan
2  | bob
3  | charlie
```

My 2nd level invoices table

```
id | client_id | paid
1  | 1         | 0
2  | 1         | 1
3  | 2         | 1
```

And my 3rd level services table

```
id | invoice_id | amount
1  | 1          | 5.00
2  | 1          | 10.00
3  | 2          | 5.00
4  | 3          | 10.00
```

And my desired outcome is

```
id | name    | amount_owing | amount_paid
1  | alan    | 15.00        | 5.00
2  | bob     | null         | 10.00
3  | charlie | null         | null
```

I can get something that doesnt take into account whether they are paid or not

```
SELECT
    clients.email,
    jnt.*
FROM clients
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        invoices.client_id,
        SUM(amount) AS invoice_total_paid
    FROM
        invoices,
        services
    WHERE 
        invoices.id = services.invoice_id 
    GROUP BY
        invoices.client_id
) AS jnt ON clients.id = jnt.client_id
```

which gives me

```
id | name    | client_id | invoice_total
1  | alan    | 1         | 20.00
2  | bob     | 2         | 10.00
3  | charlie | 3         | null
```

but it doesn't divide up whether invoice was paid or not (and the subsequent paid and owing totals). Any help much appreciated

Comment: You're SQL statement seems incomplete. Was there a copy/paste typo when adding it to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the expected result using *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN i.paid = 0 THEN s.amount ELSE 0 END) AS amount_owing,
       SUM(CASE WHEN i.paid = 1 THEN s.amount ELSE 0 END) AS amount_paid
FROM clients AS c
LEFT JOIN invoices AS i ON c.id = i.client_id
LEFT JOIN services AS s ON i.id = s.invoice_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ad8b/1)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
...
SUM(IF(paid=1,amount,0)) AS amount_paid,
SUM(IF(paid=0,0,amount)) AS amount_owning
...
```